# Is it possible to add wordpress blog to my existing html site?

Tags: html

I have html site and i want to add blog on it, i was thinking to add wordpress in the same folder as my website and just to connect them via link, does  anybody know how to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "connect them via link". Do you mean having your HTML site continue on `example.com` and then have your WordPress blog at `example.com/blog`? If that's the case, then I'd recommend installing WordPress in the subfolder `/blog`. It would be helpful if you [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/397222/edit) to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: As @PatJ just mention, your question is not clear. If you want to have your existing site: mysite.com and mysite.com/blog or blog.misite.com both of them will work, you can make the Wordpress installation in a subfolder.